# Realm Swift - Retrieve Objects by filtering on relationship

Tags: swift, realm

Here is my problem... I am looking around and trying all kind of things but it doesn't work... Surely nothing amazing but I got stuck.

I have 2 tables : `Category` and `Company`. Company has a relationship to Category :  `dynamic var categoryRelation : Category?`

It work super fine I can see my records in RealmBrowser.

But now I want to show my companies on a list filtered by Category. 
So first I send my category object from `CategoryViewController` to `CompanyViewController` through a segue. Works fine I can see my object on the other side.

But how should I use `filter()` to filter my records? If I do this :

```
var selectedCategoryId: Object?
var arrayOfCompanies = try! Realm().objects(Company)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "categoryRelation == %@", self.selectedCategoryId!)
    arrayOfCompanies = arrayOfCompanies.filter(predicate)    
}
```

My list is totally empty. If I take off the filter, I get my list but not filtered and all my records appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will offer you another solution, which is "Inverse Relationships". Read [this](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#relationships) and try this:

```
//find all Companies that have 'selectedCategoryId' as their categoryRelation property
let arrayOfCompanies = selectedCategoryId.linkingObjects(Company.self, forProperty: "categoryRelation")
```

Comment: Sorry, my property label isn't really accurate... it is called selectedCategoryId because first I tried to pass only the id... as I would have done it on a 'regular' SQL request :D
But it is a full object.

Comment: Actually in my example I am trying to compare 2 realm objects.
I also spent a long time these days to the documentation but I didn't get that the linkingObjects applied to my situation. I'll try that. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well I was sure it was something stupid... I was too focused and I forgot to pay attention to the whole picture...
For development purposes, In my first ViewController I was sending my category object by doing this : listCompaniesTableViewController.selectedCategoryId = categories[0] and you got it already, none of my companies were related to categories[0]...

Thanks for your help. Btw, my approach was finally working since the beginning. But working doesn't necessarily means it is the best way. So I am now wondering what is the best practice for that scenario : yours or mine?

Comment: Well as a matter of fact I would suggest you to add this to your Category class if you are going to do this frequently: `var companies: [Company] {
        return linkingObjects(Company.self, forProperty: "categoryRelation")
    }` By doing this you can access to all companies in a category by just doing `anyCategory.companies`. If you are not going to need this query frequently I guess it doesn't matter but personally I prefer using built-in functions as they are usually more concise, clear and fast.

Comment: That's an answer. Thanks a lot ;0)

Comment: bcamur, sorry I tried to figure out your last message about using anyCategory.companies.
I dont understand how and where to do that. Do you have a little bit more example please? Thanks

Comment: You need to add a computed property to your Category class. Like this: `class Category: Object {
   //define any other property you want id, name etc.
   var companies: [Company] { return linkingObjects(Company.self, forProperty: "categoryRelation") }
}` After doing this you can use `companies` like any other property. So if you have a category defined as `let category1 = realm.objects(Category).first` you can then say `let companiesInCategory1 = category1.companies`

Comment: sorry for the editing, new lines are lost in the comments

Comment: Thanks and sorry for my late reply.
I tried what you explained and created a property in my class. 
But I get this error : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Linking object only available for objects in a Realm.'
I reply late because I tried to figure it out but I can't find the reason.
Have you ever experienced this?

Comment: I'm not sure why you get that error. Maybe first you need to add (save) the category object to Realm.